# Anaconda - can't install package offline after downloading it

Tags: python, command-line, conda, package-managers

I'm trying to install some packages on a remote machine (with GPUs) that is not connected to the internet.

(Some people have suggested I should be using Docker and I may well do that but here's one last chance to get this working).

FYI: I'm following the [instructions here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html).

What I've done so far:

1. Downloaded Anaconda `Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh` file and installed it on the remote machine

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.6.14
```

Then downloaded the desired package from [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu/files) and moved it to the remote machine.

```
$ ls pkgs-for-anaconda/linux-64/*tensorflow*
pkgs-for-anaconda/linux-64/tensorflow-gpu-1.9.0-hf154084_0.tar.bz2
```

2. Setup a new channel which is the file path on the local file system.

```
$ conda config --prepend channels file:///home/billtubbs/pkgs-for-anaconda
```

Excerpt from config to confirm this worked:

```
channels:
  - file:///home/billtubbs/pkgs-for-anaconda
  - defaults
```

3. Install the package

```
    $ conda install pkgs-for-anaconda/linux-64/tensorflow-gpu-1.9.0-hf154084_0.tar.bz2
    Preparing transaction: done
    Verifying transaction: done
    Executing transaction: done
```

4. Index the packages

```
$ conda index pkgs-for-anaconda/
Subdir: noarch: 100%|████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 81.80it/s]
(base) [billtubbs@localhost ~]$ ch: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]s]05 [00:00<00:00, 750741.03it/s]
```

**Is the issue that it looked in no noarch instead of linux-64?**

5. Try to install the package

When I use the following to create a new environment with the desired package:

```
$ conda create -n tf tensorflow-gpu
```

I get:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-gpu -> _tflow_190_select==0.0.1=gpu
  - tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==1.9.0

Current channels:

  - file:///home/billtubbs/pkgs-for-anaconda/linux-64
  - file:///home/billtubbs/pkgs-for-anaconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

What I don't understand is that it shows my channel exists.  And it even seems to be looking for the right version (1.9.0).  But it says it can't find it.

Just to confirm, I did the following:

```
$ conda search tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
tensorflow-gpu                 1.9.0      hf154084_0  pkgs-for-anaconda   
tensorflow-gpu                 1.9.0      hf154084_0  pkgs/main
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here is some of the output from

```
$ conda list --show-channel-urls

...

sympy                     1.3                      py37_0    defaults
tblib                     1.3.2                    py37_0    defaults
tensorflow-gpu            1.9.0                hf154084_0    file:///home/billtubbs/pkgs-for-anaconda
terminado                 0.8.1                    py37_1    defaults
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0    defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you that you uninstall the current version of anaconda that you have, when I downloaded the last version of anaconda i got some problems, I remenber that I could'nt install for example tensorflow or matplotlib..
The best version to work with tensorflow or matplotlib is having one anaconda with `python 3.6.` Try to install `Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64` or `Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` which was released in `2017-05-26.`

[Anacoda versions](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/)

And then try to install tensorflow, matplotlib, pandas, numpy but before run

```
conda update conda
```

To update some packages of anaconda.
And you will install those the packages/libraries without problems,

Best Regards.
PD: I also tried to install docker however I got more problems than using python with pip, that's why I think anaconda is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure why conda installs tensorflow with Python 3.7.  I guess you can't rely on package managers to make good decisions all the time...